# Compare and display multiple JSONs containing historical data

Tags: javascript, json, compare, schema

I have multiple dynamic JSON object containing historical data and I want to display the comparison side by side (if possible on table) with Javascript.

Comment: Add the sample JSON and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the Stack Overflow help center.